# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 doitbackground

Tags: android, json, eclipse, google-maps, android-asynctask

im beginner in android and trying to make android map travel , but my marker can't shown . because some error in my logcat, and notif:unfortunately app has stop working. can you help me? (sorry for my bad english)

here's my MAINACTIVITY:

```
package id.meita.redproject;

import id.meita.redproject.entity.hotelpku;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private GoogleMap       map;
    private JSONHelper      json;
    private ProgressDialog  pDialog;

    private ArrayList<hotelpku> listhotelpku;
    private static String       URL_API = "http://10.0.3.2/api/hotelpku.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        json = new JSONHelper();
        new AsynTaskMain().execute();
        setupMapIfNeeded();
    }
    /**
     * initialize map
     */
    private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
        if (map == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
            map = supportMapFragment.getMap();

            if (map != null) {
                setupMap();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Setup Map
     */
    private void setupMap()
    {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        moveToMyLocation();
    }
        private void moveToMyLocation()
        {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            Location location =
                    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false));
            if (location !=null)
            {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude()), 13));
                        }
                         }




                     @Override
                     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
                     {

                     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                     return true;
                     }

                     @Override
                     protected void onResume()
                     {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     super.onResume();

                     int resCode =
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
                     if (resCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
                    {
                     GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resCode, this, 1);
                     }
                     }
                     private class AsynTaskMain extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
                     {

                         protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
                         {
                             pDialog.dismiss();
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                             {

                                 public void run()
                                 {
                                     for (int i = 0; i < listhotelpku.size(); i++)
                                     {
                                         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                         .position (new
                                                 LatLng(listhotelpku.get(i).getLat(),listhotelpku.get(i).getLng()))
                                                 .title(listhotelpku.get(i).getNama())
                                                 .snippet(listhotelpku.get(i).getAlamat()));

                                     }
                                 }
                             });
                                         super.onPostExecute(result);
                         }

                         protected void onPreExecute()
                         {
                             super.onPreExecute();
                             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                             pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
                             pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                             pDialog.show();
                         }

                         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                         {
                             JSONObject jObject = json.getJSONFromURL(URL_API);
                             listhotelpku = json.gethotelpkuAll(jObject);
                             return null;
                         }
                     }

                     }
```

Here's JSONHelper class:

```
package id.meita.redproject;

import id.meita.redproject.entity.hotelpku;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONHelper
{
    private InputStream     is              = null;
    private JSONObject      jsonObject      = null;
    private String          json            = "";

    private final String    TAG_HOTELPKU    = "hotelpku";
    private final String    TAG_ID          = "id";
    private final String    TAG_NAMA        = "nama";
    private final String    TAG_ALAMAT      = "alamat";
    private final String    TAG_LAT         = "lat";
    private final String    TAG_LNG         = "lng";
    private final String    TAG_ROUTES      = "routes";
    private final String    TAG_LEGS        = "legs";
    private final String    TAG_STEPS       = "steps";
    private final String    TAG_POLYLINE    = "polyline";
    private final String    TAG_POINTS      = "points";
    private final String    TAG_START       = "start_location";
    private final String    TAG_END         = "end_location";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url)
    {
        Log.d("TAG","URL Request ->" + url);
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        try
        {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);


        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<hotelpku> gethotelpkuAll(JSONObject jobj)
    {
        ArrayList<hotelpku> listhotelpku = new ArrayList<hotelpku>();

        try
        {
            JSONArray arrayhotelpku = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_HOTELPKU);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayhotelpku.length(); i++)
            {

                JSONObject jobject = arrayhotelpku.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("TAG", "lat : " + jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG));
                Log.d("log", "muter ke " + i);

                listhotelpku.add(new hotelpku(jobject.getInt(TAG_ID), jobject.getString(TAG_NAMA), jobject
                        .getString(TAG_ALAMAT), jobject
                        .getDouble(TAG_LAT), jobject.getDouble(TAG_LNG)));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listhotelpku;
    }

    /*
     * Untuk decode Polyline
     * 
     * @params String
     * 
     * @return List<LatLng>
     */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded)
    {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len)
        {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat / 1E5, lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;

    }

    /*
     * Untuk mendapatkan direction
     * 
     * @params JSONObject
     * 
     * @return List<LatLng>
     */
    public List<LatLng> getDirection(JSONObject jObj)
    {

        List<LatLng> directions = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        try
        {
            JSONObject objRoute = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ROUTES).getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject objLegs = objRoute.getJSONArray(TAG_LEGS).getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray arraySteps = objLegs.getJSONArray(TAG_STEPS);
            for (int wi2t = 0; wi2t < arraySteps.length(); wi2t++)
            {
                JSONObject step = arraySteps.getJSONObject(wi2t);
                JSONObject objStart = step.getJSONObject(TAG_START);
                JSONObject objEnd = step.getJSONObject(TAG_END);
                double latStart = objStart.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                double lngStart = objStart.getDouble(TAG_LNG);

                directions.add(new LatLng(latStart, lngStart));

                JSONObject poly = step.getJSONObject(TAG_POLYLINE);
                String encodedPoly = poly.getString(TAG_POINTS);

                List<LatLng> decodedPoly = decodePoly(encodedPoly);
                for (int eka = 0; eka < decodedPoly.size(); eka++)
                {
                    directions.add(new LatLng(decodedPoly.get(eka).latitude, decodedPoly.get(eka).longitude));
                }

                double latEnd = objEnd.getDouble(TAG_LAT);
                double lngEnd = objEnd.getDouble(TAG_LNG);
                directions.add(new LatLng(latEnd, lngEnd));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return directions;
    }
}
```

HEre's my LOGCAT:

```
05-27 00:08:55.732: E/Trace(1998): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-27 00:08:55.872: I/Google Maps Android API(1998): Google Play services client version: 4323000
05-27 00:08:55.884: I/Google Maps Android API(1998): Google Play services package version: 4452070
05-27 00:08:55.896: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 171K, 10% free 2573K/2856K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 10ms
05-27 00:08:56.028: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 245K, 12% free 2719K/3084K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 11ms
05-27 00:08:56.092: I/fpp(1998): Making Creator dynamically
05-27 00:08:56.092: I/Google Maps Android API(1998): Google Play services client version: 4452000
05-27 00:08:56.128: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 12% free 2857K/3216K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 11ms
05-27 00:08:56.264: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 143K, 8% free 3160K/3416K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 17ms
05-27 00:08:56.276: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 3160K/3416K, paused 3ms, total 10ms
05-27 00:08:56.296: I/dalvikvm-heap(1998): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.266MB for 1127532-byte allocation
05-27 00:08:56.308: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 4261K/4520K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
05-27 00:08:56.312: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 4261K/4520K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 3ms
05-27 00:08:56.344: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 66K, 4% free 4730K/4908K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 5ms
05-27 00:08:56.348: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 4724K/4908K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
05-27 00:08:56.356: I/dalvikvm-heap(1998): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.793MB for 1127532-byte allocation
05-27 00:08:56.360: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 5825K/6012K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-27 00:08:56.368: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 5825K/6012K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 7ms
05-27 00:08:56.396: D/TAG(1998): URL Request ->http://10.0.3.2/api/hotelpku.php
05-27 00:08:56.464: D/libEGL(1998): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-27 00:08:56.468: D/(1998): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8585340, tid 1998
05-27 00:08:56.480: D/libEGL(1998): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-27 00:08:56.480: D/libEGL(1998): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-27 00:08:56.512: W/EGL_emulation(1998): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 00:08:56.524: D/OpenGLRenderer(1998): Enabling debug mode 0
05-27 00:08:56.616: W/EGL_emulation(1998): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 00:08:56.848: D/(1998): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb85b9708, tid 2023
05-27 00:08:57.180: I/Choreographer(1998): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 00:08:57.808: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 907K, 15% free 6076K/7092K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 56ms
05-27 00:08:57.808: D/dalvikvm(1998): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 48ms
05-27 00:08:57.808: D/dalvikvm(1998): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 46ms
05-27 00:08:57.812: W/dalvikvm(1998): threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6180908)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at id.meita.redproject.JSONHelper.gethotelpkuAll(JSONHelper.java:106)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at id.meita.redproject.MainActivity$AsynTaskMain.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:143)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at id.meita.redproject.MainActivity$AsynTaskMain.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-27 00:08:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     ... 4 more
05-27 00:08:58.052: I/Choreographer(1998): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 00:08:58.364: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 957K, 15% free 6351K/7420K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-27 00:08:58.388: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 68K, 14% free 6452K/7420K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 18ms
05-27 00:08:58.440: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_CONCURRENT freed 710K, 11% free 6989K/7832K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 6ms
05-27 00:08:59.232: I/Choreographer(1998): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998): Activity id.meita.redproject.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5330f044 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity id.meita.redproject.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5330f044 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at id.meita.redproject.MainActivity$AsynTaskMain.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:137)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at id.meita.redproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-27 00:09:00.316: E/WindowManager(1998):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 00:09:01.296: I/Process(1998): Sending signal. PID: 1998 SIG: 9
```

Heres manifest class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.meita.redproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
     <permission
          android:name="id.meita.redproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="id.meita.redproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDmKMij1Moz5C3FRs3s1gqXrVrpXjxKKEQ" />
        <activity
            android:name="id.meita.redproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you sure that you are running the server??

Comment: my webserver xampp, and connect my json to mysql php, and use URL http://10.0.2.2/myphp for emulator genymotion from some article. but i think the URL must be hosting/publishing. :(, i can't solve it for a week

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @mei2red: can you not remove the relevant parts of your log?

Comment: @njzk2 that's all my display logcat, i followed step by step from some article, for showing marker map, but they'd can't display.

Answer (score 0):

your error caused by network timeout

```
05-26 01:36:50.947: W/System.err(1731): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

are you sure this URL

```
http://10.0.2.2/api/hotelpku.php
```

is accessable from the mobile? [try to open it using regular web-browser installed on the mobile

extra check : remember to add INTERNET permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: yes, this URL for emulator genymotion,  i read some article, and the app just loading, and take so long then 'unfortunately ur app stopped'. i just updated my post

Comment: whatever url it was, your problem is network issue, either the emulator can't access the server, or the server is not started at all, if an installed browser on the mobile could not load the page, then you have a problem, might be config or firewall. try to run the app on mobile that have the a wifi connection over the same LAN, if still not working, then you need to disable the firewall on the PC that has the server running on,

Comment: i just resolved my problem connection with changed my URL. but FATAL EXEPTION ASynctask #1 still shown :(. in my logcat updated. thanks for help :)

Comment: @mei2red your log says you have NPE at line no. 106. Which line is that?

Comment: @Nitish in my JSONHelper class